# Parallel Q-learning

Tags: neural-network, parallel, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, pybrain

I'm looking for academic papers or other credible sources focusing on the topic of parralelized reinforcement learning, specifically Q-learning.
I'm mostly interested in methods of sharing Q-table between processes (or joining/syncing them together if each process have it's own).
I'd also appreciate a brief description of method used in linked/mentioned sources.

I should mention that I use neural network (PyBrain) as approximation.

Comment: I couldn't add pybrain as tag (too little rep.)

Comment: Done it for you :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you will like the following two papers:

Available from: http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.04296

Nair A, Srinivasan P, Blackwell S, Alcicek C, Fearon R, De Maria A, et al. Massively Parallel Methods for Deep Reinforcement Learning. arXiv preprint arXiv:150704296

Available from: http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01783

Mnih V, Badia AP, Mirza M, Graves A, Lillicrap TP, Harley T, et al. Asynchronous Methods for Deep Reinforcement Learning. arXiv:160201783

Comment: I use simple Q-learning but I guess articles about deep Q-learning would also be useful, not for my current work however.

Comment: In my opinion, although the papers are about deep q-learning the concepts are applicable to what you are doing: different agents collecting trajectories in parallel and sharing and exchanging the network parameters. Definitely can serve as inspiration.